# PHP/JavaScript apparently not detecting JSON API as valid

Tags: javascript, php, api, rest

I'm trying to make a simple API with PHP and a way to retrieve data from it in JavaScript but I keep getting the following error: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0`. The JSON is valid and I'm not sure what is causing the error...

I've tried setting headers and the data is encoded with `json_encode()` so there's not really any excuse for it to not be working.

**API link:** [removed by author]

**PHP Code:**

```php
<?php
  include("../config/connect.php");

    $method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
    $request = explode('/', trim($_SERVER['PATH_INFO'],'/'));

    ob_clean();
    header_remove();

    header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");

   if ($success) {
       http_response_code(200);
   } else {
       http_response_code(500);
   }

  // Error handling
  $username = filter_var(htmlentities($_GET['username']));

  if (!$username) {
    $api = array("Error"=>"Error: No username specified.");

    echo json_encode($api);
    exit();
  }

  $quesql = "SELECT * FROM signup WHERE username=:username";
  $query = $conn->prepare($quesql);
  $query->bindParam(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $query->execute();
  while ($getinfo = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
      $fetch_id = $getinfo['id'];
      $fetch_username = $getinfo['Username'];
      // And so forth...
  }

  if ($query->rowCount() == 0) {
    $api = array("Error"=>"Error: No such user.");
    echo json_encode($api);
    exit();
  }

  $avatar = $fetch_avatarURL == "user.png" ? "https://comiq.eddyn.net/imgs/user_imgs/user.png" : $fetch_avatarURL;
  $occ = $fetch_occupation == NULL ? "none" : $fetch_occupation;
  $bio = $fetch_bio == NULL ? "none" : $fetch_bio;
  // And so forth...

$api = array("username"=>$fetch_username, "joinDate"=>$fetch_joined, "avatarURL"=>$avatar, "occupation"=>$occ, "bio"=>$bio,
            "hometown"=>$hometown, "hobbies"=>$hobbies, "likes"=>$likes, "dislikes"=>$dislikes, "verified"=>$verified, "admin"=>$admin,
            "mod"=>$mod, "dev"=>$dev, "artist"=>$artist, "plus"=>$plus, "online"=>$online);

  echo json_encode($api);
  exit();
?>
```

**JS Code:**

```js
try {
    request('https://comiq.eddyn.net/api/profile?username=' + args[0], function (error, body) {
      var result = JSON.parse(body.body)
      const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor(colors.default)
        .setTitle(result.username)
        .addField("Occupation", result.occupation, true)
        .addField("Bio", result.bio, true)
        .addField("Hometown", result.hometown, true)
        .addField("Hobbies", result.hobbies, true)
        .addField("Likes", result.likes, true)
        .addField("Dislikes", result.dislikes, true)
        .addField("Verified", result.verified, true)
        .addField("Comiq Plus", result.plus, true)
        .addField("Online", result.online, true)
        .setImage(result.avatarURL)

      message.channel.send(embed)
    })
  } catch (err) {
    message.channel.send(client.errors.genericError + err.stack).catch();
  }
```

Comment: Look at the full response in the Network tab. There must be some HTML before the JSON.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be anything: https://prnt.sc/vsmahr @Barmar Do you think it might be a problem with using an AJAX URL with https://www.npmjs.com/package/request ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your response is JSON data.
So you should to remove the line of  `var result = JSON.parse(body.body)`.
Just use `body` as `result`.

```
try {
    request('https://comiq.eddyn.net/api/profile?username=' + args[0], function (error, body) {
      var result = body;
      const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor(colors.default)
        .setTitle(result.username)
        .addField("Occupation", result.occupation, true)
        .addField("Bio", result.bio, true)
        .addField("Hometown", result.hometown, true)
        .addField("Hobbies", result.hobbies, true)
        .addField("Likes", result.likes, true)
        .addField("Dislikes", result.dislikes, true)
        .addField("Verified", result.verified, true)
        .addField("Comiq Plus", result.plus, true)
        .addField("Online", result.online, true)
        .setImage(result.avatarURL)

      message.channel.send(embed)
    })
  } catch (err) {
    message.channel.send(client.errors.genericError + err.stack).catch();
  }
```

Comment: That fixes the error, though my results are returning back as `undefined`. Is `result.[item]` no longer what I need to get the data?

Comment: Maybe you can get the value of `body.username, body.occupation, body.hometown...` as correctly in this way.

Comment: so strange.. This is work for me. Did you ever print `body` in the console panel?

Comment: Very odd, it seems to spam my console with HTML and CSS from other pages from my site, despite there literally not being any ties with other files in the current. I think it might be due to request not being able to read AJAX URLs. Thanks anyways though.